# I need to batch convert Word (.doc) to Word Perfect documents (.wpd)

Tags: microsoft-word, batch, conversion, wordperfect

Everything I have found so far is going the other direction and few specifics.  I need to convert approximately a hundred Word documents into WordPerfect documents.  It has been more than a decade since I have needed to do anything like this and I can't remember how.  Any specific suggestions or links to solutions is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Found a link explaining how to enable [saving as a WordPerfect document](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/skissinger/archive/2007/12/10/save-to-wordperfect-from-word-2003.aspx) in MS Word 2003, but it seems that the format is not supported by latter versions of Office/Word due to security concerns.

But if WordPerfect supports RTF (you don't specify which version of Word or WP you are using) you could use [one of these scripts](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_automation_word.php) written by Rob van der Woude to automate batch converting documents from Word into RTF and then opening them in WP.

Hope this helps somewhat...